# Why rust fails type inference for Vec<_>

Tags: rust, types, annotations, type-inference, type-annotation

I don't understand why Rust fails to infer the type for `Vec<_>` in some cases. If I run this

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let s = v.iter().sum();
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0282]: type annotations needed
 --> src/main.rs:5:9
  |
5 |     let s = v.iter().sum();
  |         ^ consider giving `s` a type
```

so that I have to modify it to either

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let s = v.iter().sum::<i32>();
}
```

or

```
fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let s: i32 = v.iter().sum();
}
```

Why the type inference fails here? It correctly gets that `v` is a `Vec<i32>` so if `sum` it's on that vector why does it need `i32` to be annotated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Iterator::sum()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.sum) is generic over its return type. This allows you to e.g. sum an iterator of `&i32`s into an `i32`, since [`i32` impls `Sum<&i32>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Sum.html#impl-Sum%3C%26%27a%20i32%3E). Because of that, the compiler cannot infer the return type.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on the Chayim Friedman's answer, consider the following code:

```
use core::iter::Sum;

// here might be some complex state, e.g. a kind of "long arithmetic"
struct Consumer;

impl<'a> Sum<&'a i32> for Consumer {
    fn sum<I: Iterator<Item = &'a i32>>(_: I) -> Self {
        // here might be some complex logic
        Self
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    let s: Consumer = v.iter().sum();
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bf3021605690479cb21784ea0f3b2ee9)

You can see that the `main` function differs from your example only in the type of `s`. Therefore, without this type it's potentially ambiguous - note that the `Consumer` struct (and, consequently, its implementation) could very well be in another crate, not controlled by you. Therefore, Rust forces you to make an explicit choice, what exactly to sum into.